# ie7 clientWidth and clientHeight problems

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, offsetwidth

I've tried to get the offsetWidth and offsetHeight properties like so:

```
<div id="somediv" class="some_class_with_dimensions"></div><script...>alert(document.getElementById('somediv').offsetWidth);</script>
```

Unfortunately, on IE7 offsetWidth only works if i call in on window.onload, otherwise it just returns 0. Does anyone know any other way around this problem, because i need to immediately work with "somediv" just like in real browsers.

Comment: The closest I can test with is IE8 rendering in IE7 mode, and that works fine. Can you set up an example at jsbin or jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: The example that i've given indeed does work. The problem arises in a not-so-valid html that i have no control over with lots of tables etc. My theory is that IE doesn't know the width until it loads the parent elements. Anyway, ignore this since i had no other choice but to use dom readyness checks.

Comment: @Marius: If you found the solution, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Mufasa: i didn't find a solution and i don't know the exact cause so i took the next best thing - the dom readiness. Don't think it's worth to be marked as an answer cause i'm not satisfied with it myself.

Comment: You're correct, it won't know the offset until it draws the page. There isn't another workaround to getting that offset value, but there may be a workaround to what you are/were trying to solve. But would need more data to address that.